# how to convert epoch time stored in nested field to date mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a nested field `msgs.crtDtTm` inside a `mongodb` which has epoch date (`1554120000`)stored as string. I need to convert `msgs.crtDtTm` to `Date` format to apply `$gte` (which is not working in String format).

```
cond: { $gte: [ "$msg.crtDtTm", "1554120000" ] }
```

I tried this but greater than operation not performed. It is returning all the nested elements without filtering.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert string to date by this command :

```
new Date("1554120000")
```

Like this :

```
db.YourCollection.find({"created_at" : { $gte : new Date("1554120000") }});
```

in your example :

```
cond: {$msg.crtDtTm : { $gte:  new Date("1554120000") }}
```

Let me know the result please .

This [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate) is also useful

Comment: Date constructor cannot parse such strings. ```new Date("1554120000")``` results in
```ISODate("0NaN-NaN-NaNTNaN:NaN:NaNZ")```

Comment: /* 1sample doc */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ba25eb7af8b1a2e684828a4"),
    "_class" : "com.cccccccc.raDocument",
    "msgs" : [ 
        {
            "tpe" : "Renewal Kit",
            "uId" : "test.np9s9ocvet", 
             "crtDtTm" : "1537367735427",           
        },  
  {
            "tpe" : "Renewal Kit",
            "uId" : "test.9qzi2b6fr",            
            "crtDtTm" : "1537369818723",
           
        }         
    ],   
    "webId" : "123456789", 
    "dob" : "06/17/1955"
}

Comment: i need to filter msgs with"crtDtTm"  greater than eg: april 1,2019 .I tried to filter msgs

Comment: {
      $project: {
         items: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$msgs",
               as: "msg",
               cond: {"$msg.crtDtTm" : { "$gte":  new Date("1554120000") }}
            }

Answer (score 0):

Once your time **april 1,2019** being converted into ms and then to type of string in your code, it would be easy that way(as converting one element *vs* n values in DB - altogether it might be easy for that format to be converted into ms in code), then use this query to retrieve elements that match your criteria :

```
db.yourCollection.aggregate([
    {$match: {'msgs.crtDtTm': {$gt: '1554120000'}}},
    {$addFields: {
        msgs: {$filter: {
            input: '$msgs',
            as: 'msg',
            cond: {$gt: ['$$msg.crtDtTm', '1554120000']}
        }}
    }}
])
```

You could achieve similar using `$unwind` on msgs & then `$match` finally `$group` or `$match` to start with, which ever is feasible you can go ahead. Something like this :

```
db.yourCollection.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        'msgs.crtDtTm': { $gt: '1554120000' }
    }
},
{ $unwind: "$msgs" },
{
    $match: {
        'msgs.crtDtTm': { $gt: '1554120000' }
    }
}, { $group: { _id: '$_id', msgs: { $push: '$msgs' }, docs: { $first: '$$ROOT' } } }, { $addFields: { 'docs.msgs': '$msgs' } }, { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$docs' } }])
```

Lastly, It would be a better idea if you can store the same format which will be used to query.